# matplotlib no space between some axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, spacing

Using matplotlib I'm trying to plot 3 charts in a grid, then a single chart with 3 different Y ranges but the same X scale. I can achieve that by using the `hspace` command but it affects the whole document. Is it possible to do it only for the one chart?

My current code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.69,16.53))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(5, 2)
# chart 1,2,3
fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
# chart 4
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, :])
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[3, :])
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
fig.add_subplot(gs[4, :])
# adjust and save
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.0)
fig.savefig('report.pdf')
```

Produces:

[all charts without spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BhDu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
plt.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
```

Replace the pad value with another number to increase/decrease spacing.

Comment: I added it between plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.0) and fig.savefig('report.pdf') and results are that all subplots are spaced (like without hspace at all), but 3 bottom subplot need to be one chart